# How can I style an html select box to omit drop down arrow for print?

Tags: css

I have an html select element which I would like to style for print so that it just looks like the selected text.  How can I hide the drop down arrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

There is nothing in the standards that specifies that the select element has to have an arrow to indicate to the user that it has options to choose from, or how those options are shown. As those visual elements are not defined, there is naturally nothing defined for changing them.

You just have to display a different element when printing.

Comment: This may have been correct at the time, but now, Rowan's answer is correct.

Comment: @EM-Creations: It was in the CSS3 spec, but is now dropped. http://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css4-ui#dropped-css3-features

Answer (score 25):

The below works for Firefox, Safari, Chrome and a few others

```
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

For IE support look at http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/

Answer (score 3):

In webkit you can specify:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Not sure about the other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One idea:  for the print operation, swap the combo box with a label control.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide the selected text value next to the dropdown and hide it via CSS. Then use a [print stylesheet](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) to show the text and hide the dropdown when printing.