# How to show the image in the select box in the google chrome browser

Tags: html, css

I want to show the image in the select drop-down box in the google chrome.
only in google chrome not showing the image, but all browser show the image.

Google chrome image look like...
[image]

All browser show image look like...
[image]

So i want to make same select box in all browser.

My code is..

```
.selectbox_bg {
    background: url("images/contact_texbox_bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
    border: medium none;
    color: #5D5C5C !important;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    width: 255px;
}
```

Please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: try adding : -webkit-appearance:none;

Comment: its a bug in Chrome, there is no transparency color for select boxes, and you must set it for option as well, but i think u can regenerate that effect easily with css3 (which is supported by chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,put your background image in `background:url` and paste rest of code and adjust all parameters accordingly.

```
background:url(selectbox.png) no-repeat !important;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
border: medium none;
color: #5D5C5C !important;
font-size: 15px;
height: 33px;
line-height: 33px;
padding: 6px 10px;
width: 255px;
```

Comment: i have add the your css, but after using drop-down button is not show in the select box, i think this is problem ""-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;""

Comment: @NishantPatel I think it's not possible to show drop-down button while using image.You have to create a image with the drop-down button as you show in your question. for information see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439163/how-can-i-style-an-html-select-box-to-omit-drop-down-arrow-for-print

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css

```
select{
    background-color: #9BD300;   
   border-radius:4px; 
    border:1px #99CC00 solid; 
    padding:4px;
    width:150px
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6VPBp/1/)**

Or try this

```
.selectbox_bg {
    background: url("images/contact_texbox_bg.png");
    background-position: 0 0;        
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-color:transparent;
    border: medium none;
    color: #5D5C5C !important;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    width: 255px;
}
```

Comment: i want to put the back-ground image...like background: url("images/contact_texbox_bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;

Comment: Check the updated answer. It would be easier if you can post your image link