# How do I hide the arrow button on a html form drop down list?

Tags: html, css, forms, drop-down-menu, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I style an html select box to omit drop down arrow for print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439163/how-can-i-style-an-html-select-box-to-omit-drop-down-arrow-for-print)

I am looking at creating a print page for a html form, and in the form I wish to only display the text of the selected option, not the box or the drop down button. How can this be done? Preferably with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can refer this link that will shed some light on your need
http://imar.spaanjaars.com/240/how-do-i-hide-screen-elements-when-a-page-is-printed





<html>
<head>
  <title>Non Printable Stuff</title>
  <link href="/Styles/MainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="/Styles/PrintStyle.css" rel=" stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">

  <style type="text/css" media="print">
    .NonPrintable
    {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="I am hidden" class="NonPrintable">
</body>
</html> 


</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="I am hidden" class="NonPrintable">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really what i'm looking for. I know how to hide elements etc, but the problem is that if you hide the selector for the drop down, the text also hides along with it.

Comment: for text box we can set style like input
{
border-style: none;
}

Comment: Yeah, that has been done. I am trying to get rid of the drop down arrow though.